# Python Requests cannot connect to Squid Proxy

Tags: python, http, proxy, python-requests, squid

I have a squid proxy that requires authentication. In `squid.conf` I am using:

`auth_param digest program /usr/lib64/squid/digest_pw_auth -c /etc/squid/passwords`

`auth_param digest realm proxy`

`acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED`

`http_access allow authenticated`

From this I can expect the authentication method to be `http digest`.

Here is my python code:

`from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth`

```
auth = HTTPDigestAuth("user", "pass")

r = requests.get( "http://www.google.com", allow_redirects=True, headers=Configuration.HEADERS, proxies=proxy_list(), auth=auth )
```

I am receiving this error:

`407 Proxy Authentication Required`

I have also tried authenticating with:

`auth = HTTPProxyAuth('user', 'password')`

and:

`http://user:password@ip`

With no luck...

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: What is `proxies_list()`?

Comment: Just a function to generate a proxy list dictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HTTPDigestAuth` doesn't authenticate you with the proxy, it authenticates you with the website. Right now Requests doesn't have any built-in way of using Digest Auth with a proxy, [and there are no plans to add built-in support](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1866#issuecomment-32386120).

You'll have to either use with the proxy (by putting your credentials in the proxy URL, e.g. `proxies={'http': 'http://user:password@domain.com'}`), or write your own authentication handler for Proxy Digest Auth.

Comment: I thought this may be the case, sadly using user:password did not work with digest auth so I had to revert my squid setup to use basic http authentication which worked. I may write an auth handler in the future. Thanks for your input.